# perl stacking switch case statements

Tags: perl

In php I can stack case statements, can I do equivalent with perl?

```
        switch($myValue)             
        {            
            case "one":
            case "two":
            break;
            case "three":
            break;
            default:
            break;
         }
```

Comment: Do you mean [Allowing fall-through](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html#Allowing-fall-through)?

Comment: @Mike: Switch.pm was an experiment, now deeply regretted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Switch statements](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) in Perl<sup>*>= 5.10*</sup> are implemented using `given` and `when` constructs. It is highly flexible due to smart-matching of the value passed to `given`.

```
use feature qw( switch );
use strict;
use warnings;

given ($value) {
    when ( [qw/one two/] ) {
        # do something
    }
    when ('three') {
        # do some other thing
    }
    default {
        # default to something
    }
}
```

You could even write `when ( [qw/one two/] )` as `when ( /one|two/ )`.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, that would be:

```
use 5.010;
given( $myValue )             
{            
    when ( [qw<one two>] ) { say; }
    when ( "three" )       { say "I'm $_";  }
    default                { say qq{DEFAULT for "$_"};  }
 }
```

And to test it:

```
use 5.010;

foreach my $myValue ( qw<one two three four> ) 
{
    given( $myValue )             
    {            
        when ( [qw<one two>] ) { say; }
        when ( "three" )       { say "I'm $_";  }
        default                { say qq{DEFAULT for "$_"};  }
     }
}
```

And it prints:

```
one
two
I'm three
DEFAULT for "four"
```

---

Perl allows *another* type of fall-through, with the `continue` statement. But the criteria of *both* cases have to be satisfied. Thus:

```
given( $myValue )
{
    when ( 'one' ) { say 'one!'; continue; }
    when ( 'two' ) { say 'two!'; }
}
```

makes no sense, because it will never be a case where `$s ~~ 'one' && $s ~~ 'two'`, but if you made the second case:

```
    when ( /\bo|o\b/ ) { say q/has 'o'!/; }
```

the fall-through condition is capable of being true. One caveat: since everything complies with `default`, if you have a `default` case the continue will hit it if nothing else. `continue` seems to say "Ok, now look for what other predicates apply."

I mention this simply because it looks deceptively like a "fall-through operator of sorts", but it's really a "look again" operator.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl < 5.10, you can fake it with subrefs in a hash:

```
my %switch = (
    foo => sub { do_something() },
    bar => sub { do_something_else() },
);
exists $switch{$check_var} ? $switch{$check_var}->() : do_the_default_case();
```

It doesn't give you fall-through (no Duff's Device), although that's a dubious feature.

Comment: This doesn't look as though it supports a default option, or handle mismatched switch values ('baz' in the example would give a problem).  It may be the best that can be done.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler The default option is achieved through an `if` statement or the conditional operator.  It is always a good idea to add an existence check when using a dispatch table, even if all it does is `die` with an error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to fall through, there is the `continue` statement, which lets you do so explicitly

```
given($foo) {
  when (/x/) { say '$foo contains an x'; continue }
  when (/y/) { say '$foo contains a y' }
  default    { say '$foo does not contain a y' }
}
```

rather than implicitly (as by omitting the `break` statement in the OP's example).

Sample snipped from [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements).

Answer (score -1):

The following is working for me:

[`use Switch;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Switch.html)

Comment: Please don't recommend Switch.pm. It's a source filter and can lead to nasty subtle bugs. The given/when syntax that was added in Perl 5.10 is far safer.

Comment: Many enterprises run versions below 5.10 and Switch.pm is an easy solution if what is being written is a simple chore script.

Comment: Well, I'd hope that those enterprises would be planning to upgrade to a more recent version of Perl at some point :-) But anyway, Switch.pm is a source filter - and that means that no sane programmer would use it in production code.